# How can I get padding in a scrollable flex-grow?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a pretty simple layout consisting of one parent element with a fixed height and two children, one with `flex-grow: 1`, `flex-shrink: 1`, a padding, and `overflow: auto`, and the other with `flex-grow: 0` and `flex-shrink: 0`.

What I want to happen is for the `1 1` child to get a scrollbar when it overflows, but for it to still have a padding all around. It's best illustrated by [this JSBin](https://jsbin.com/cubaqikitu/edit?html,css,output). If you scroll the `foo`s, you'll see that there is no padding on the bottom.

The padding is there if I set `flex-shrink: 0` on the element, but then it no longer scrolls.

Code:

```css
#a {
 border: 1px solid black;
 height: 300px;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}

#b {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  background: blue;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 1rem;
}

#c {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background: red;
  height: 3rem;
}

p {
  background: green;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="a">
    <div id="b">
      
      <p>foo</p>
      <p>foo</p>
      <p>foo</p>
      <p>foo</p>
      <p>foo</p>
      <p>foo</p>
      <p>foo</p>
      <p>foo</p>
      <p>foo</p>
      <p>foo</p>
      <p>foo</p>
      <p>foo</p>
      <p>foo</p>
      <p>foo</p>
      <p>foo</p>
      <p>foo</p>
      <p>foo</p>
      <p>foo</p>
      <p>foo</p>
      <p>foo</p>
    </div>

      <div id="c">
        thing
      </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Huh, looks like it does. I'm using Firefox Developer Edition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be one of the many shortfalls of using flex with IE.  A workaround is to wrap the content of b and then put the padding on the wrapper:

```css
#a {
 border: 1px solid black;
 height: 300px;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}

#b {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: blue;
  overflow:auto;
}

#b-inner {
  padding: 1rem;
}

#c {
  background: red;
  height: 3rem;
}

p {
  background: green;
  margin:0;
}

#hack {
  height: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  <div id="b">
    <div id="b-inner">
      <p>foo</p>
      <p>foo</p>
      <p>foo</p>
      <p>foo</p>
      <p>foo</p>
      <p>foo</p>
      <p>foo</p>
      <p>foo</p>
      <p>foo</p>
      <p>foo</p>
      <p>foo</p>
      <p>foo</p>
      <p>foo</p>
      <p>foo</p>
      <p>foo</p>
      <p>foo</p>
      <p>foo</p>
      <p>foo</p>
      <p>foo</p>
      <p>foo</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="c">
    thing
  </div>
</div>
```